# macro defined in spec file is getting substituted in generated file but not working

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec, dpdk, ninja, meson-build

I have a requirement where in I need to **upgrade the DPDK version to 21.11.1**. I am running the build in the **containerized environment** I have installed both **meson and ninja** for the same.I have defined few macro in spec file as following :

```
    %define __ninja /bin/ninja
    %define __ninja_common_opts -v %{?_smp_mflags}
    %define ninja_build %{__ninja} %{__ninja_common_opts}
    %define meson_build %ninja_build -C %{_vpath_builddir}
```

In the %build section of the spec file I am using commands as `%meson_build`

But these commands are getting substituted in the generated SH file due to that my build RPMs build is not going through. I have added a screenshot of generated sh file. I have also added a screenshot of the spec file.

The installed version of the meson and ninja are as follows.

```
    docker exec -it 73c3c42919a3 sh
    sh-4.2# rpm -qa | grep "ninja"
    **ninja-build-1.8.2-1**
    sh-4.2# rpm -qa | grep "meson"
    **meson-0.49.2-1**
```

I am new to building RPMs. It would be a great help if you can tell me why macros are substituted and not running and also if in case there is a change in the flow in which commands should get executed let me know that too. Any help is appreciated.

meson-log.txt : snippet last few lines

```
Message: 
=================
Libraries Enabled
=================

libs:
    kvargs, telemetry, eal, ring, rcu, mempool, mbuf, net, 
    meter, ethdev, pci, cmdline, metrics, hash, timer, acl, 
    bbdev, bitratestats, bpf, cfgfile, compressdev, cryptodev, distributor, efd, 
    eventdev, gpudev, gro, gso, ip_frag, jobstats, kni, latencystats, 
    lpm, member, pcapng, power, rawdev, regexdev, dmadev, rib, 
    reorder, sched, security, stack, vhost, ipsec, fib, port, 
    pdump, table, pipeline, flow_classify, graph, node, 

Message: 
===============
Drivers Enabled
===============

common:
    cpt, dpaax, iavf, octeontx, octeontx2, cnxk, qat, sfc_efx, 
    
bus:
    auxiliary, dpaa, fslmc, ifpga, pci, vdev, vmbus, 
mempool:
    bucket, cnxk, dpaa, dpaa2, octeontx, octeontx2, ring, stack, 
    
dma:
    cnxk, dpaa, hisilicon, idxd, ioat, skeleton, 
net:
    af_packet, ark, atlantic, avp, axgbe, bnx2x, bnxt, bond, 
    cnxk, cxgbe, dpaa, dpaa2, e1000, ena, enetc, enetfec, 
    enic, failsafe, fm10k, hinic, hns3, i40e, iavf, ice, 
    igc, ionic, ixgbe, kni, liquidio, memif, netvsc, nfp, 
    ngbe, null, octeontx, octeontx2, octeontx_ep, pcap, pfe, qede, 
    ring, softnic, tap, thunderx, txgbe, vdev_netvsc, vhost, virtio, 
    vmxnet3, 
raw:
    cnxk_bphy, dpaa2_cmdif, dpaa2_qdma, ntb, skeleton, 
crypto:
    bcmfs, caam_jr, ccp, cnxk, dpaa_sec, dpaa2_sec, nitrox, null, 
    octeontx, octeontx2, openssl, scheduler, virtio, 
compress:
    octeontx, zlib, 
regex:
    octeontx2, 
vdpa:
    ifc, sfc, 
event:
    cnxk, dlb2, dpaa, dpaa2, dsw, octeontx2, opdl, skeleton, 
    sw, octeontx, 
baseband:
    acc100, fpga_5gnr_fec, fpga_lte_fec, la12xx, null, turbo_sw, 
gpu:
    

Message: 
=================
Content Skipped
=================

libs:
    
drivers:
    common/mvep:    missing dependency, "libmusdk"
    common/mlx5:    missing dependency, "mlx5"
    net/af_xdp: missing dependency, "libbpf"
    net/ipn3ke: missing dependency, "libfdt"
    net/mlx4:   missing dependency, "mlx4"
    net/mlx5:   missing internal dependency, "common_mlx5"
    net/mvneta: missing dependency, "libmusdk"
    net/mvpp2:  missing dependency, "libmusdk"
    net/nfb:    missing dependency, "libnfb"
    net/sfc:    missing dependency, "libatomic"
    raw/ifpga:  missing dependency, "libfdt"
    raw/ioat:   replaced by dmadev drivers
    crypto/armv8:   missing dependency, "libAArch64crypto"
    crypto/ipsec_mb:    missing dependency, "libIPSec_MB"
    crypto/mlx5:    missing internal dependency, "common_mlx5"
    crypto/mvsam:   missing dependency, "libmusdk"
    compress/isal:  missing dependency, "libisal"
    compress/mlx5:  missing internal dependency, "common_mlx5"
    regex/mlx5: missing internal dependency, "common_mlx5"
    vdpa/mlx5:  missing internal dependency, "common_mlx5"
    gpu/cuda:   missing dependency, "cuda.h"
    

Build targets in project: 963
Found ninja-1.8.2 at /bin/ninja
```

Thanks

[image: Error Log]
[image: Generated SH File]
[image: SPECFILE]

Comment: can you please clarify the following 1) are you trying to update dpdk version forHost os or trying install dpdk in container environment? 2) If you are trying to install you should use `ninja -C %{build_dir} install`, but you are not using to updated the lib folder 3) in the explanation you are stating `that my build RPMs build is not going through` 4) none of the screenshot are available 5) there is no mention of error or error logs.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I am upgrading the dpdk version from 17.02 to 21.11.1. Once rpm is build that will be packaged into iso file. Which we use for our needs. I have updated the screen shot of error. We use container only to create iso file.

Comment: so you are having issuesin rpm packing and not docket image build and install. Is that right?

Comment: @VipinVarghese Yes with rpm packing as rpm build is failing, I have tried multiple option  but no luck. What should be the right order of commands ? DPDK documentation says meson <options> build && cd build
ninja.

Comment: your assumption ` meson <options> build && cd build ninja` builds rpm is incorrect. instead ` meson <options> build && cd build ninja` is used to buidl dpdk libraries only. Hence i have been highlighting and asking your expecting, `rpmbuild` is actually used for building or packing libraries into rpm.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Okay, Actually  I am new to this. Just started with build process. I am looking for rpm build. How should i use commands inside spec file to get the required rpm file. Every time i use meson or ninja commands i get into issue like meson.build file or ninja.build is not there.Sometime its build the dpdk in build folder which will be having all so file, meson log, ninja.build file. But still rpm builds fails.

Comment: @shivachittora since you have mentioned you are new to this, my recommendation is first simply run on linux console to build dpdk libraries. then rry using `rpmbuild` to build package. Once done you can replicate the shell script steps correctly.

Comment: checking your images `ninja` build is comment and `Error` is plugged in. Looks like the shell scripts is faulty?

Comment: @VipinVarghese shell script is temporary, its getting generated from spec file. Due to this only I raised this question. As every time I am running any commands from spec file these type of error message being added to temp shell script. Its getting corrupted  due to this.